# How do access the tab details in C# from Umbraco 7?

Tags: c#, umbraco7

Please see following image.

[Umbraco7 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdA4q.png)

I am using Umbraco 7. You can see in the image that I have 'General Messages' tab.
I have saved all error messages in that and i need to access these error messages from the code, can I do that in Csharp ?

Comment: Form the code where, on the front end or in the CMS? Can you be a bit more specific about what your are trying to do please?

Comment: From my Csharp code.I want to access Umbraco values in my csharp code

Comment: Can any one have answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have a template assigned to the sign up page, and that you want to get at the messages on that View.

That being the case, you can use either:

```
@Umbraco.Field("yourPropertyAliasHere")
```

or

```
@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("yourPropertyAliasHere")
```

The main difference is that Umbraco.Field has a bunch of useful additional parameters for things like recursive lookup.

If you want get at the properties from within some random C# in your Umbraco site that isn't related t the actual signup page, assuming you have an Umbraco Helper, you can do the following:

```
var page = Umbraco.TypedContent(1234); //replace '1234' with the id of your signup page!

var message = page.GetPropertyValue<string>("yourPropertyAliasHere");
```